# Where can I get LEGO bricks to build a life size wall?

Tags: shopping

I would like to create the structure, meaning walls of my stand in an exhibition, made by LEGO bricks, so I wonder if I can order great quantities of bricks just to create this and if I can talk to an engineer who can design for me a particular product made by Lego's bricks.

Who can I speak to? Can I receive a quotation for that?

Comment: This sounds like the job of a master LEGO builder, but I'm sure you can do it too! This does sound like an expensive project, however.

Comment: I would say that [bricklink.com](http://www.bricklink.com/) is one of the best places to buy bricks from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always go to Ebay and buy some (or should I say, a lot) of the 1x16 bricks. I don't know the dimensions of your exhibition, so I cannot give any further information. Good luck with that project!

Answer (score 2):

I'd ask someone like [Warren Elsmore](http://warrenelsmore.com/) to help with this. He's done many unique creations for organisations all over the world, and he's written 3 books about LEGO.

Although I would also consider this idea.
[These guys](http://www.aplaceforeverything.co.uk/home-storage/lego-storage-bricks-and-heads) rocked up to BRICK 2014 in London this past weekend and built the walls of their stand with their product of LEGO storage bricks. It worked great. The dimension are huge and still recognisable as LEGO. It would also be heaps cheaper than trying to build it from standard size bricks.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a Lego Users Group in your area, see if you can place a [LUGBULK order through them](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/06/the-lego-lugbulk-program/).

Otherwise, your best bet is probably [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/).